# Modal showing old data before loading the new one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, fetch

I have a modal with some data fetched from an api, for the first time everything works fine, then when I close the modal and I open it with different data it first shows me the old data with the loading progress and then it updated the data, I wanna show just the progress bar without the old data and then when the new data is ready I show it ?

```
  <CustomModal
      open={Boolean(openModalState)}
      onClose={onClose}
      title="Sorting Log"
      maxWidth="85%"
      renderActionButton={
        <ActionButton
          label="Reload"
          onClick={e => {
            e.stopPropagation()
            fetchData()
          }}
        />
      }
    >
      <div className={classes.logScreen}>
        <LogsViewBody
          loading={loading && !data}
          loadMore={loading && Boolean(data)}
          error={error}
        >
          <InfiniteLogs data={data} loadMore={loadMore} hasMore={hasMore} />
        </LogsViewBody>
      </div>
    </CustomModal>
```

Comment: What about `<InfiniteLogs data={loading ? {} : data} loadMore={loadMore} hasMore={hasMore} />`?

Comment: @PeterLehnhardt I have tried this approach, the problem is that I have an infinite scroll component in the modal, and with this code when I attend the bottom of the component and the component try to load more content it brings me to the top again because loading is changed and the component rerenders.

Answer (score 0):

What about delete data/set them to "" etc. onClose?

Or what I did many times - use ternary -> `loading ? showLoading : showData`

**.. in JSX it could be written as:**

`loading ? <my-loading-component /> : <my-content-component />`